# add a custom python bokeh widget without JavaScript

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

I want to create a custom bokeh widget without using JavaScript, i.e. without following the bokeh documentation on [Adding A Custom Widget](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/widget.html).  The example below demonstrates the creation of a custom widget in PyQt4 (I use this a lot), and what I would expect to work in bokeh along with the error message I get.

Is there some other way to create a custom widget in bokeh without using JavaScript?  Specifically I am trying to create a custom slider with small - and + buttons on each side that increment / decrement the slider by 1 step.  I want to use this custom widget in many applications so I want it defined as its own class with on_change method linked to the slider on_change method.  There are other custom widgets in bokeh I want to make (without JS!) and I would like to know if this is even possible.

```
# this works as a base to develop custom PyQt4 widgets
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class NewWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
widget = NewWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())


# this does not work as a base to develop custom bokeh widgets
# when run, a tab opens with the message
# Bokeh Error
# Model `NewWidget' does not exist. This could be due to a widget
# or a custom model not being registered before first usage.
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import Widget

class NewWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

new = NewWidget()
show(widgetbox(new))
```

UPDATE: The specific custom widget I am attempting to create is a Slider with a Button on each side (on the left labeled '-', on the right labeled '+') that change the Slider value by 1 step.  This is used to fine-tune the value of a Slider so the mouse is not required to exactly hit a target value.  I created this custom widget by linking default Slider and Button objects and it renders in the browser, but the callback functionality is not working (specifically the Slider 'on_change' method).

[image: Slider With Buttons]

Is this custom widget straightforward to implement with bokeh and JS?  Is there an online reference that may provide hints without diving too deep into JS.

Comment: `.on_change` requires a Bokeh server (that's where the python callback gets executed) Are you saying this does not work with a server app? Or is this not in the context of a server app? In any case it seems like this should be do-able more generally with a line or two of JS and `.js_on_change` callback: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-generic-events which does not require a server

Comment: For buttons in particular, you'd actually still want to use the `callback` property to set a `CustomJS` callback. See below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bokeh is a library for generating plot and visualization apps in modern browsers (or embedded HTML widgets). It's composed of two essential parts. The python side of Bokeh is really just a sophisticated "wrapper" or "binding" that ultimately produces a declarative JSON document, which in turns drives a JavaScript library (BokehJS) that actually does all the work in the browser.

Extending Bokeh necessarily means providing both sides of that equation: You have to provide a (typically very minimal) python declaration of the extension, that really just specifies the information needed to automatically generating the JSON format I described above. And you also have to provide a JavaScript (or TypeScript) implementation for the extension, that actually does all the work in the browser.

Since browsers have no ability to run Python code, the implementation *necessarily has to be JavaScript*.

There are some libraries such as Flexx and Brython that can "transpile" python into JavaScript. You might find them useful as a means to avoid writing JavaScript directly, but these libraries often have quirks and specific deficiencies in certain use cases, so YMMV.

---

Here is a complete example that uses a `CustomJS` callback on a button to update a slider:

```
from bokeh.models import Button, CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.io import output_file, show

slider = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=0, step=0.1)

button = Button()
button.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(slider=slider), code="""
    slider.value += 0.1
""")

output_file("foo.html")

show(row(slider, button))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I understand now there is no way to create a custom bokeh widget without JS.  Could you please read the UPDATE to my original post and let me know if you are able to offer any guidance here.  _Transpiling_ does not sound like a robust approach.  Thanks again!